# Нет доступа к таблице в БД ef через include?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
            using (FacultDB db=new FacultDB())
            {
                var ar=db.FacultyTable.Include(f=>f.students).ToList();//ошибка не удается преобразовать тип стринг так как он не является типом делегата
            }

public class Faculty
    {
        public int  facultyId{get;set;}
        public string facultyName { get; set;}
        public virtual ICollection<Person> students{get;set;}
        public Faculty()
        {
            students = new List<Person>();
        }
    }
 public class Person
    {
        public int personId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public Faculty faculty { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: `ошибка не удается преобразовать тип стринг так как он не является типом делегата` так прямо и пишет? Приведите дословный текст ошибки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проверьте пространства имен, скорее всего не хватает: 
using System.Data.Entity; 
или 
using System.Linq;

Comment: Первого не хватает, расширение Include определено именно там.